# problems with Fragment onBackPress

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

in my navigation drawer there are 5 menu items.one of them is about us item.when I click on this item, I call AboutUsFragment and show it(its content is just a text).but when I click onBackPress, fragment is gone but its texts remains on my activity.how can I solve this problem?what`s it related to?!

select item of navigation drawer in my activity:

```
public void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            if (!Constants.login_state) {
                fragment = new LoginFragment();
            } else {
                Logout();
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            Constants.filter = false;
            Constants.gender = "-1";
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;

        case 2:
            Constants.filter = false;
            Constants.gender = "2";
            StyleFragment.SortingMode = 1;
            fragment = new StyleFragment();
            break;

        case 3:
            Constants.filter = false;
            Constants.gender = "1";
            StyleFragment.SortingMode = 1;
            fragment = new StyleFragment();
            break;

        case 4:
            fragment = new AboutUsFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentManager.replace(R.id.rl_container, fragment);
        fragmentManager.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentManager.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
    } else {
        Log.e("HomeActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

and AboutUsFragment:

```
public class AboutUsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

private View view;
private TextView about_us_fragment_text_view;

public static AboutUsFragment newInstance() {
    AboutUsFragment fragment = new AboutUsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, container, false);
    Casting(view);
    about_us_fragment_text_view.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.about_us));
    ChangeUIFont.ChangeFont((ViewGroup) view, getContext());

    return view;
}


//casting parameters
public void Casting(View v){
    about_us_fragment_text_view= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.about_us_fragment_text_view);
}}
```

onBackPress in my activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (SearchOpened) {
        lv_searchResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SearchOpened = false;
    } else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

---------------------------------------AfterSearching-------------------------------------------

Finally I found the solution!

in my fragment I added below code:

```
public static final String FRAGMENT_NAME = AboutUsFragment.class.getName();
```

and in my activity,I set the tag of fragment when I call it,instead of null!

```
fragmentManager.replace(R.id.rl_container, fragment,fragmentName);
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: sometimes it occurs! not all the time!

Comment: also post your `onBackPressed` code in your Activity and Fragment

Comment: But I should say I didn`t define onBackPress in AboutUsFragment as you see in my codes!

Comment: just destroy your fragment on OnBackPressed, used finish();

Comment: @Zahra tell me r u used custom toolbar on your application.. if yes then i can post good answer here for your solution

Comment: @SagarChavada unfortunately yes I used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used this method instead of onBackPressed

if you have toolbar then here is my solution,
type under the oncreate method below toolbar,

```
    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
  //  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

}

and set this code in your manifest file for your fragment

```
    <activity android:name=".yourCurrentFragment">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".whichActivityYouWantToGo" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: can you explain about it? I got confused about its reason!!

Comment: bcz on onBackPress event only exit your current activity, not its instance, thats why yout text appear on display, if you still want to used onBackPress then use finish() in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
      getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
```